# Supremum and infimum of an intersection of bounded sets proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Given A, B are **bounded** subsets of R. Prove the following:

1. $\sup(A∩B) ≤ \min(\sup A,\sup B)$
2. $\inf(A∩B) ≥ \max(\inf A,\inf B)$

They're quite similar so just solving/proving one of them is good enough for me. I am unable to come up with a "rigorous" proof as to why this is true.

Comment: Can you give an intuitive proof as to why it is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\min(\sup A, \sup B)$.

Case 1: $M=\sup A$.

By definition of supremum, for any $a\in A$, we have $a\leq M$.

Then for any $x\in A\cap B\subseteq A$, we have $x\leq M$. This means that $M$ is an upper bound of $A\cap B$.

Since $\sup(A\cap B)$ is by definition the least upper bound, we have $\sup(A\cap B)\leq M$.

Case 2: $M=\sup B$. Exact same conclusion.

So $\sup(A\cap B)\leq\min(\sup A,\sup B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x\in A$ and so $x\leq\sup A$. Also, $x\in B$ and so $x\leq\sup B$.

So for all $x\in A\cap B$, we have $x\leq\min(\sup A,\sup B)$.

So $\min(\sup A,\sup B)$ is an upper bound for $A\cap B$ and thus $\sup A\cap B \leq \min(\sup A,\sup B)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove I nicier result

Show that if $$X\subseteq Y$$ and Y is bounded, then $$\inf Y \leq \inf X \leq \sup X \leq \sup Y$$.

And then, you show that if $X,Y$ are bounded, then: $$\sup X \cup Y = \min(\sup X,\sup Y)$$ and $$\inf X\cup Y= \max( \inf X, \inf Y)$$

Since for any sets A,B, we have $A\cap B \subseteq A\cup B$, the results follows imediately

Comment: Are you sure? I choose X the unit interval and  Y = [0,2]. Now $$\sup X \cup Y = \sup Y = 2,$$ while $$\min(\sup X,\sup Y) = \sup X.$$